# Automation Notifications

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to build an automated notification for sales orders.

In the message area, I need the sales order line items to be displayed in the message.

I can only get the first line item to display in the message. How do I get all the line items to display?

[Message Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/522zn.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can include information from document detail lines in notifications by adding a foreach loop to the body of the notification template in the HTML format. For instance, you can use the following construction for the Transactions view of your Sales Order:

```
<foreach view="Transactions”> 
    ((Transactions.TranDesc))<br> 
</foreach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!