# Acumatica Notification Template syntax

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica you can create a customized email template which can contain certain syntax such as if statement and for loop. You can also do the same in the report designer.

I can't find any resource or information on how to do a an if statement, reference values, and do a for loop in the notification templates. I can look at an existing report and get proper syntax for the designer tool.

Could someone please either point me to the documentation for these templates, or provide an easy example of an if statement, for loop, and referencing values.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out if it's possible to have if conditions in the notification templates? I have yet to come across any documentation or links saying it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be support in notification templates for simple foreach tags, like this:

```
<foreach view="Transactions”> 
    ((Transactions.TranDesc))<br> 
</foreach>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809916/1748460) from [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624448/gabriel)